# How to change Flot visitor's graph plotting color

Tags: php, css, flot

I am using jquery Flot to show daily page loads of a site using visitors example graph.

http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/visitors/

I need to change the plotting color (which is yellow now) to blue.

Comment: Just set a color property on the series setup. [Docs Here](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/visitors/)

Comment: Thanks,I added series:{color:"blue"} to options